# MongoDB C# Driver: $where with javascript function

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the MongoDB C# driver (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver), how can I create a query which uses $where with a JavaScript function?

Here's an example of the query I'm trying to create if using a GUI like MongoVUE:

```
{ $where: 'function() { return true }' }
```

I'm aware that I can use the legacy driver to do this, but wondered if there's a way using the new API only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a builder helper for it because it's not something you should normally use. When you need it, you can drop down and build it out of a BsonDocument.

```
new BsonDocument("$where", new BsonJavaScript("function() { return true; }"));
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks very much! When you say you shouldn't normally use this I'm not going to be using this for day to day querying, but it seems like a very powerful way to create advanced queries which would be great for reports. Do you mean this should be avoided entirely in production code? Oh and while I've got you, is there an ETA for the release of version 2.1 of the C# driver? Thanks! :)

Comment: It should be avoided unless it's needed. Anything that executes javascript on the server isn't meant for live queries. In your case, for reports, it's perfectly fine.

ETA: not yet. The feature we are waiting on is LINQ and I'm working on that right now.